# How to pass the ID of the current user rendered on the page to an action handler method in JSF 2?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF page in which I show the details of a given user:

```
<h:form>

    <p>
    <h:outputLabel value="User Name" for="userName" />
    <h:outputText id="userName" value="#{userController.user.name}" />
    </p>

    <p>
    <h:outputLabel value="Email" for="email" />
    <h:outputText id="email" value="#{userController.user.email}" />
    </p>

    <p>
        <h:commandLink value="Edit" action="#{userController.edit(userController.user.id)}" />
    </p>
</h:form>
```

This works fine with the exception of the Edit commandLink. When I click it, I expect `userController.edit` to be passed the ID of the user that's currently being rendered on the page.

However looks like as `userController` is a request scoped bean that has a `@PostConstruct` method that assigns a new User to the user field, always 0 is being passed to the action method as the ID of a new instance of User is `null` which apparently gets converted to 0.

How can I fix this controller/page, without changing the scope of the controller, to pass the correct ID to the edit action? Here's the code for the controller:

```
@Model
public class UserController {

    @Inject
    @UserRepository
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Inject
    private UserTransaction tx;

    private User user;

    public String edit(Long id) {
        System.out.println("id = " + id);
        // fetch the user with id from the db
        return "edit";
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        user = new User();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I should set the value of `userController.user.id` using a hidden field, right?

Comment: Apart from the concrete problem, the approach is a bit weird. You aren't preserving some concrete user at all, but you are always preserving a blank user instance in the postconstruct. Why would the user ID be relevant? Didn't you oversimplify the code example? Also, passing the user ID as parameter which originates at the **same** bean as you're submitting the form to makes no sense. You would just access it as a property right inside the action method.

Comment: Yes I have simplified the code. The `UserController` is being used in other places as well. The `edit` action brings up the page to edit the user. Then another action will save it in the DB.

Comment: Some times ago I had to use similar thing. Look at example in my answer. It works.

Answer (score 0):

The approach is weird but I can imagine when you need this. (e.g. you don't wand to write to session and flash scope don't work in distributed environment etc.). BTW if you can't use session scope consider using flash scope.

Apart from correctness of the approach, try adding aditional field to the bean:

```
protected Long currentId;

public Long getCurrentId() {
    return currentId == null ? user.getId() : currentId;//or simply return it, I don't know how you play with the user field
}

public void setCurrentId(Long currentId) {
    this.currentId = currentId;
}
```

Remove parameter from `edit` action and use `currentId` field, and to your view add param (hidden field will not work here):

```
<f:viewParam name="id" value="#{userController.currentId}" />
```

Then in action you can get user id from the previous view simply accessing this.currentId.
And BTW, try load your User from another place, not int @PostConstruct. If you create user in @PostConstruct then when you are in edit method the currentId will be from previous view, and user.id will be from @PostConstruct. So if you don't want to store user in session scope, but use only request scope you have to persist it immediately after creation (e.g. in database). In edit method you have to get it back using currentId.